# jssor slider - many sliders on one page

Tags: javascript, jssor

I saw many posts for placing multiple instances of the jssor slider on a page. However, I want to dynamically add multiple sliders, depending on PHP queries and the content in my CMS. So, the page has to be ready to handle 2 or 20 sliders ... or more.

There are many posts on stackoverflow that show how I can add two sliders as follows...

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$("slider2_container", options);
```

... and then refer to each ID (i.e. slider2_container) when I refer to the slider. But what if I have 20 sliders (or more), I don't want to have to have 20 different lines for the sliders (or worry about MORE if there are MORE than 20).  I would prefer to have something for a general slider... I don't write javascript, but something like (I know this is wrong, but the * below refers to any #) ...

```
var jssor_slider* = new $JssorSlider$("slider*_container", options);
```

I saw this post...
[Jssor non-jquery slider dynamic amount multiple slider on one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062537/jssor-non-jquery-slider-dynamic-amount-multiple-slider-on-one-page)
... but it is left unanswered. I will populate the page and the slider with information from my CMS (which I am customizing with galleries).

And, as I mentioned, I've seen many other posts for 2 or 3 sliders ... but nothing to handle an unknown number.  Please let me know.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jssor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            var _CaptionTransitions = [];
            _CaptionTransitions["L"] = { $Duration: 900, x: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["R"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["T"] = { $Duration: 900, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["B"] = { $Duration: 900, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["ZMF|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["RTT|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };
            _CaptionTransitions["RTT|2"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 3, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} };
            _CaptionTransitions["RTTL|BR"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, y: -0.6, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };
            _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|LR"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 15, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|L"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 1, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic} };
            _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|R"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 2, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic} };

            var options = {
                $FillMode: 2, //[Opt] The way to fill image in slide, 0 stretch, 1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide), 2 cover (keep aspect ratio and cover whole slide), 4 actual size, 5 contain for large image, actual size for small image, default=0
                $AutoPlay: true, //[Opt] Whether to auto play, this option must be set to true, default=false
                $AutoPlayInterval: 4000, //[Opt] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default=3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1, //[Opt] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default=1

                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true, //[Opt] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuint, //[Opt] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad
                $SlideDuration: 1200, //[Opt] Duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20, //[Opt] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                //$SlideWidth: 600, //[Opt] Width of every slide in pixels, default is width of 'slides' container
                //$SlideHeight: 300, //[Opt] Height of every slide in pixels, default is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 0, //[Opt] Space between each slide in pixels, default=0
                $DisplayPieces: 1, //[Opt] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default=1
                $ParkingPosition: 0, //[Opt] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default=0.
                $UISearchMode: 1, //[Opt] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $PlayOrientation: 1, //[Opt] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
                $DragOrientation: 1, //[Opt] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                $CaptionSliderOptions: { //[Opt] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                    $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$, //[Req] Class to create instance to animate caption
                    $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions, //[Req] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                    $PlayInMode: 1, //[Opt] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default=1
                    $PlayOutMode: 3 //[Opt] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default=1
                },

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: { //[Opt] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$, //[Req] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2, //[Req] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 1, //[Opt] Auto center navigator, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default=0
                    $Steps: 1, //[Opt] Steps to go for each nav request, default=1
                    $Lanes: 1, //[Opt] lanes to arrange items, default=1
                    $SpacingX: 8, //[Opt] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default=0
                    $SpacingY: 8, //[Opt] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default=0
                    $Orientation: 1 //[Opt] Orientation of the nav, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default=1
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: { //[Opt] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$, //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 1, //[Req] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 2, //[Opt] Auto center, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default=0
                    $Steps: 1 //[Opt] Steps to go for each navigation request, default=1
                }
            };

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                if (bodyWidth)
                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 1280));
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
            ScaleSlider();

            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from passing an id as variable to initial jssor slider, you can also pass an element as variable. So, the following 2 approaches are all legal.

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

var containerElement = document.getElementById("slider1_container");
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerElement , options);
```

In this manner, given you have 20 slider elements, you can initialize it as below,

```
var containerElements = [...];   //slider container elements in an array
for(var i=0; i<containerElements.length; i++) {
    new $JssorSlider(containerElements[i], options);
}
```

Comment: Not sure how the first option works (it looks like it only works for slider1_container).  I see how the second option works ... but for that example, each page could have a different number of sliders (one page could have 5, and another could have 20, and another could have 32).

Using ...
var containerElements = [...]; ... I'd have to insert each id name into the containerElement (which is hard when you don't know how many elements you have).

Comment: You can put element id or element instance to the array. And initialize jssor slider as stated above.

Comment: I get that. So, for 3 sliders, I would do: var containerElements = [slider1_container, slider2_container, slider3_container] 
... but how do I do this for an unknown number of items? That is the question.

Comment: Check out the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062537/jssor-non-jquery-slider-dynamic-amount-multiple-slider-on-one-page/30112600#30112600

Comment: <script>
    jssor_sliderb_starter = function (containerId) {
    ...
    };</script>
What goes in the "..." area?  This isn't setup like the examples on the jssor site, so I'm not sure how to add this to my code?  (also, the link you sent has 2 answers... and doesn't say which works)

Comment: I also added my complete header javascript above... (it currently works if I only have 1 slider)

Comment: Anyone else out there?

Comment: Since no help was working, I decided to switch from jssor slider to bxslider, which I found was much easier to configure and customize.

Answer (score 0):

Since no help was working (and people stopped answering), I decided to switch from jssor slider to bxslider, which I found was much easier to configure and customize.